# WebApp giving DEBUG error on some of the browsers

Tags: python, django, deployment

After a quick research I was able to build a very basic Django app to find the weather using the openweathermap api.I deployed it using Digital Ocean after getting a free domain from freenom.Problem is when I sent to to some of my friends to see it wont open in some of them, giving the error as follows:
`Change that to <code>False</code>, and Django will
 display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.`
Thanks! Here is the link to the app:
http://currweather.cf
PS:It's not much as I am new to Django

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.py, You need to add `DEBUG=False`

Comment: How you deployed your application? like apache, nginx?

Comment: Yes , I used digital ocean, putty and wscp

Comment: Can you explain how you are running your application. Seems you are using gunicorn and your application is in development mode. Also it throws errors in some line.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand by what you mean by "how?"

Comment: I am asking about how you are serving your application. I checked with builtwith. You are using nginx right. Your site is working. You need to fix the bugs in your code. Think that 404 page sent by nginx.

Comment: yes you are right about the nginx part.Can you plz tell me how can I detect the errors that are showing up coz when I open the site it works fine for me on my device.

Comment: Its showing me Key error on 
/home/django/django_project/weather/views.py in find
    tempk = (data['main']['temp']) 
You can check your nginx error logs

Comment: Can u plz tell me how to view the error logs? I tried everything. I am using winscp and putty